# Search String: Find and Grep

Tags: command-line, find, grep

There must be a better / shorter way to do this:

```
# Find files that contain <string-to-find> in current directory
#   (including sub directories) 
$ find . | xargs grep <string-to-find>
```

Also, to search only e.g. HTML files:

```
 # find . | grep html$ | xargs grep <string-to-find>
```

Thanks beforehand!

Comment: Not sure what do you mean by better?

Comment: I was imagining that maybe we can use just one command; or, anything that is more efficient.

Comment: Passing all the file names to `grep` with `xargs` will not work if the list of files is too long.

Comment: @Radu: Thanks for pointing this out. Is the limit documented somewhere?

Comment: @Siku-Siku.Com, you can find it defined as `ARG_MAX` in [`include/linux/limits.h`](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux-2.6.git;a=blob_plain;f=include/linux/limits.h) in the Linux kernel, and it has a default value of `131072`.

Comment: Wow... that's a serious, serious detail! Awesome, thanks!

Comment: That's the maximum number of arguments that can be passed to a command. xargs obtains its data trough pipe (not as arguments). For each single line read from input xargs calls command (grep in this case) with that single line passed as argument (so grep receives only one file to search, not all of them). Given example does not suffer from ARG_MAX limit.

Comment: @Ivan, `xargs` does indeed receive the argument data through the pipe, but then it needs to run the command with the arguments it compiled from the data it received. That's where the maximum number of arguments comes into play. If `xargs` needs to execute a command with a million arguments (what it received from `stdin`), then the OS will complain.

Comment: @Ivan, also, `xargs` does not run the command with each argument. It compiles a list of all arguments and _then_ runs the command.

Comment: @Radu ok I really needed to check this so.. The documentation says this:  xargs reads items from the standard input, delimited by blanks or newlines, and executes the command (default is /bin/echo) *one or more times* with any initial-arguments followed by items read from standard input. Now "one or more time" was rather confusing so I wrote a simple script that writes number of args it received and ran find / | test.py. The result is that xargs calls my script bunch of times but with hundreds of parameters.

Comment: @Ivan, you're right, I noticed this in the manual too. I actually used this command very often though, and depended on it even in some production scripts and it worked the way I expected it to work. But I never sent it too many arguments, so I haven't seen it execute the command more than once yet. Thanks for testing, it's good to know.

Comment: I actually always used it with an assumption that executes one command per input line til now. So thanks for enlightening me :).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
find . -name \*.html
```

or, if you want to find files with names matching a regular expression:

```
find . -regex filename-regex.\*\.html
```

or, if you want to search for a regular expression in files with names matching a regular expression

```
find . -regex filename-regex.\*\.html -exec grep -H string-to-find {} \;
```

The `grep` argument `-H` outputs the name of the file, if that's of interest. If not, you can safely remove it and simply use `grep`. This will instruct `find` to execute `grep string-to-find filename` for each file name it finds, thus avoiding the possibility of the list of arguments being too long, and the need for `find` to finish executing before it can pass its results to `xargs`.

---

To address your examples:

```
find . | xargs grep <string-to-find>
```

could be replaced with

```
find . -exec grep -H string-to-find {} \;
```

and

```
find . | grep html$ | xargs grep <string-to-find>
```

could be replaced with

```
find . -name \*.html -exec grep -H string-to-find {} \;
```

Comment: Would you care to explain the `{} \` constructs at the end of the command?

Comment: If you're not using something exotic xargs should not be waiting for find to complete. Modern operating systems stream data trough pipes as find outputs data xargs processes it, there is no single buffer beeing filled until find completes (thats how pipes in MSDOS used to work). To test this simply go to / and execute find take a note how long it takes for find to complete (or interrupt it if you're bored). Then run find / | xargs you can easily see that xargs outputs data from find as it arrives.

Comment: @Siku-Siku.Com, `find` replaces `{}` with the current file name.

Comment: @Ivan, even though `xargs` receives data as soon as `find` outputs it, it cannot run the command until it has all the arguments. For that to happen, `find` must finish sending them.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what do you mean by better, my first thought was something like this:

```
grep <string-to-find> $(find -regex .*\.html)
```

But that's worse because result of the find would be accumulated somewhere in shells memory and then sent as a huge chunk of input arguments

The only imporvement I see too your suggestion is

```
find -regex .*\.html | xargs grep <string-to-find>
```

That way find performs all the filtering and you still retain piped processing

Answer (score 2):

If this is going to be a common search utility you're going to utilize, you may want to take a look at [ack](http://www.betterthangrep.com/), which combines both the `find` and the `grep` together into this functionality that you're looking for. It has fewer features than `grep`, though 99% of my searches are suited perfectly by replacing all instances of `grep` with `ack`.

Besides the other answers given, I also suggest this construct:

`find . -type f -name "*.html" -print|xargs -I FILENAME grep "< string-to-find>" FILENAME`

Even better, if the filenames have spaces in them, you can either quote `"FILENAME"` or pass a null-terminated (instead of newline-terminated) result from `find` to `xargs`, and then have `xargs` strip those out itself:

`find . -type f -name "*.html" -print0|xargs -0 -I FILENAME grep "< string-to-find>" FILENAME
                             here --^ and --^`

Here, the name `FILENAME` can actually be anything, but it needs to match both

`find . -type f -name "*.html" -print0|xargs -0 -I FILENAME grep "< string-to-find>" FILENAME
                                           here --^                           and --^`

Like this:

`find . -type f -name "*.html" -print0|xargs -0 -I GRRRR grep "< string-to-find>" GRRR
                                           this --^                       this --^`

It's essentially doing the same thing as the `{}` used within the `find` statement itself to state "the line of text that this returned".  Otherwise, xargs just tacks the results of `find` to the END of all the rest of the commands you give it (which doesn't help much if you want `grep` to search inside a file, which is usually specified *last* on the command-line).

Answer (score -1):

Pretty sure that's the only way. You'll have to reiderate through each folder, then through each subfolder and check each file.
Only other thing i can think of is in server code throw the directory and file structure into a LINQ query and then you can do a sql-like query against it. but then the server is going to end up doing pretty much the same thing.