# Recursively move files of certain type and keep their directory structure

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, find, grep

I have a directory which contains multiple sub-directories with *mov* and *jpg* files.

```
/dir/
  /subdir-a/  # contains a-1.jpg, a-2.jpg, a-1.mov
  /subdir-b/  # contains b-1.mov
  /subdir-c/  # contains c-1.jpg
  /subdir-d/  # contains d-1.mov
  ...         # more directories with the same pattern
```

I need to find a way using command-line tools (on Mac OSX, ideally) to move all the *mov* files to a new location. However, one requirement is to keep directory structure i.e.:

```
/dir/
  /subdir-a/  # contains a-1.mov
  /subdir-b/  # contains b-1.mov
              # NOTE: subdir-c isn't copied because it doesn't have mov files 
  /subdir-d/  # contains d-1.mov
  ...
```

I am familiar with [`find`, `grep`, and `xargs`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8138635/583539) but wasn't sure how to solve this issue. Thank you very much beforehand!

Comment: You could, if you have the space, `cp` the directory and just `find newdir ! -name '*.mov' -delete`. It ḿay not be the best solution, but as a practical matter it's likely to finish before you get a better answer here.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It depends slightly on your O/S and, more particularly, on the facilities in your version of `tar` and whether you have the command `cpio`.  It also depends a bit on whether you have newlines (in particular) in your file names; most people don't.

**Option #1**

```
cd /old-dir
find . -name '*.mov' -print | cpio -pvdumB /new-dir
```

**Option #2**

```
find . -name '*.mov' -print | tar -c -f - -T - |
(cd /new-dir; tar -xf -)
```

The `cpio` command has a pass-through (copy) mode which does exactly what you want given a list of file names, one per line, on its standard input.

Some versions of the `tar` command have an option to read the list of file names, one per line, from standard input; on MacOS X, that option is `-T -` (where the lone `-` means 'standard input').  For the first `tar` command, the option `-f -` means (in the context of writing an archive with `-c`, write to standard output); in the second `tar` command, the `-x` option means that the `-f -` means 'read from standard input'.

There may be other options; look at the manual page or help output of `tar` rather carefully.

This process copies the files rather than moving them.  The second half of the operation would be:

```
find . -name '*.mov' -exec rm -f {} +
```

Comment: Can we can use `-delete` option of `find` instead of `-exec rm`?

Comment: You could use `-print0` / `-0` to take care of the newline problem, and you should use `-delete` instead of `rm -f`.

Comment: Yes, you probably can use `-delete` if your variant of `find` supports it.  It wasn't an option in 7th Edition UNIX (and actually still isn't an option in POSIX 2008). I tend to forget about the non-standard options so that what I write has a maximal chance of working on many systems.  Similarly with the `-print0 / -0` options; I'm not sure whether `tar` or `cpio` supports them; specifically, neither `cpio` nor `tar` on MacOS X 10.7.2 supports it.  That's why I put the 'no newlines in filenames' caveat into the answer.  Anything else is fine.

Comment: When I add -delete the file is deleted before cpio. How to avoid that?

Comment: @arek: I'd separate the copy and delete operations, as in my answer.  It's one of those "Doctor, Doctor, it hurts when I …" situations. If you're worried that some `.mov` files might arrive between the time of the first and second passes, then I'd arrange to run a shell script from the `find` command, and the script would copy the files from its command line and then delete the originals.

Comment: I don't think you've been properly loved for this answer (particularly the cpio part).  There are literally 30 or 40 other stackexchange answers that suck compared to this | and show up on Google before this one.  Shame on you SEO criteria!  Great Answer +1.

Answer (score 5):

ASSERT: No files have newline characters in them.  Spaces, however, are AOK.

```
# TEST FIRST: CREATION OF FOLDERS
find . -type f -iname \*.mov -printf '%h\n' | sort | uniq | xargs -n 1 -d '\n' -I '{}' echo mkdir -vp "/TARGET_FOLDER_ROOT/{}"

# EXECUTE CREATION OF EMPTY TARGET FOLDERS
find . -type f -iname \*.mov -printf '%h\n' | sort | uniq | xargs -n 1 -d '\n' -I '{}' mkdir -vp "/TARGET_FOLDER_ROOT/{}"

# TEST FIRST: REVIEW FILES TO BE MOVED
find . -type f -iname \*.mov -exec echo mv {} /TARGET_FOLDER_ROOT/{} \;

# EXECUTE MOVE FILES
find . -type f -iname \*.mov -exec mv {} /TARGET_FOLDER_ROOT/{} \;
```

Comment: For creation of folders wouldnt find . -type d -exec mkdir -vp /TARGET_FOLDER_ROOT/{} \; work also ? Are there generally any traps regardig eg symbolic links?

Answer (score 4):

Being large files, if they are on the same file system you don't want to copy them, but just to replicate their directory structure while moving.
You can use this function:

```
# moves a file (or folder) preserving its folder structure (relative to source path)
# usage: move_keep_path source destination
move_keep_path () {
  # create directories up to one level up
  mkdir -p "`dirname "$2"`"
  mv "$1" "$2"
}
```

Or, adding support to merging existing directories:

```
# moves a file (or folder) preserving its folder structure (relative to source path)
# usage: move_keep_path source destination
move_keep_path () {
  # create directories up to one level up
  mkdir -p "`dirname "$2"`"
  if [[ -d "$1" && -d "$2" ]]; then
    # merge existing folder
    find "$1" -depth 1 | while read file; do
      # call recursively for all files inside
      mv_merge "$file" "$2/`basename "$file"`"
    done
    # remove after merge
    rmdir "$1"
  else
    # either file or non-existing folder
    mv "$1" "$2"
  fi
}
```

Comment: Can this be expanded to work with wildcards? e.g. `move_keep_path /path/to/files/*.txt /dest`

Answer (score 3):

It is easier to just copy the files like:

```
cp --parents some/folder/*/*.mov new_folder/
```

Answer (score 2):

from the parent directory of "dir execute this:

```
find ./dir -name "*.mov" | xargs tar cif mov.tar
```

Then cd to the directory you want to move the files to and execute this:

```
tar xvf /path/to/parent/directory/of"dir"/mov.tar
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work if you want to move all `mov` files to a directory called new location -

```
find ./dir -iname '*.mov' -exec mv '{}' ./newlocation \;
```

However, if you wish to move the `mov` files along with their sub-dirs then you can do something like this -

#### Step 1: Copy entire structure of /dir to a new location using `cp`

```
cp -iprv dir/ newdir
```

#### Step 2: Find `jpg` files from newdir and delete them.

```
find ./newdir -iname "*.jpg" -delete
```

#### Test:

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] ls -R a
a.mov aa    b.mov

a/aa:
aaa   c.mov d.mov

a/aa/aaa:
e.mov f.mov
[jaypal:~/Temp] mkdir d
[jaypal:~/Temp] find ./a -iname '*.mov' -exec mv '{}' ./d \;
[jaypal:~/Temp] ls -R d
a.mov b.mov c.mov d.mov e.mov f.mov
```

Comment: The first command will create files `/newlocation/dir/path/under/olddir/file.mov` (rather than `/newlocation/path/under/olddir/file.mov`); you need to start the `find` command in the top-level directory from which you want to move files.

Comment: Thanks Jon, I added couple of tests, didn't really notice any difference. Is it because of the example I am using?

Comment: The first command I referred to was the `find` command, not the various `cp` commands.

Comment: Sorry my bad Jon. I did a test with the `find` command. It moves the files to new directory. It doesn't move the sub-dir as I had stated in the answer.

Comment: Urgh...yes, I got it wrong too.  My initial comment is wrong (I was thinking of what happens when names are streamed to `cpio`, I guess).  So, there was a problem; it just wasn't what I diagnosed as the problem.  My (half) bad.

Comment: No problem Jon. Thanks for all the feedback though. :)

Answer (score 0):

I amended the function of @djjeck, because it didn't work as I needed. The function below moves a source file to a destination directory also creating the needed levels of hierarchy in the source file path (see the example below):

```
# moves a file, creates needed levels of hierarchy in destination
# usage: move_with_hierarchy source_file destination top_level_directory
move_with_hierarchy () {
    path_tail=$(dirname $(realpath --relative-to="$3" "$1"))

    cd "$2"
    mkdir -p $path_tail
    cd - > /dev/null

    mv "$1" "${2}/${path_tail}"
}
```

example:

```
$ ls /home/sergei/tmp/dir1/dir2/bla.txt
/home/sergei/tmp/dir1/dir2/bla.txt
$ rm -rf tmp2
$ mkdir tmp2
$ move_with_hierarchy /home/sergei/tmp/dir1/dir2/bla.txt /home/sergei/tmp2 /home/sergei/tmp
$ tree ~/tmp2
/home/sergei/tmp2
└── dir1
    └── dir2
        └── bla.txt

2 directories, 1 file
```